# Easily add mount points to Ubuntu

Tags: windows, mount, partitioning

Is there a nice, possibly GUI way to add mount points to partitions in Ubuntu?

For some reason, the mount point for my windows `NTFS` partition which was recognized during the installation is gone. In "Computer" the library still exist, but there's no mount point in `fstab` or `mtab`.

How can I add it again, so that it'll be nicely accessible from gnome as it used to be?

Comment: mtab is suppose to be a list of what is currently mounted, it is a bit deprecated though, the same contents is in `/proc/mounts` where it is automatically updated by the kernel.

Comment: Look at this answer:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/88523/creating-a-mount-point-if-it-does-not-exist/941726#941726 - instructions for installing `pmount` to make this simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NTFS Configuration Tool

You can install it from Ubuntu Software Center.

Answer (score 7):

`pysdm` is a gui to your `/etc/fstab`.  It has a basic wizard and makes it easy to configure your drives and where they mount.
[image]

Comment: That's what I use and it works flawlessly. For a NTFS drive under options I use "nls=iso8859-1,umask=000". nls sets the character set and umask gives root access to all files/folders on the drive. For more info on how to configure this see http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=872197.

Comment: wich GUI you are using? looks nice

Comment: @Zabba, sorry I kinda fell off the site for a while.  That'd be the elementary theme on GNOME.

Answer (score 1):

Nautilus uses gvfs to do mounting without modifying `/etc/fstab`. Can you access the partition in Nautilus? If you're trying to access it from a shell prompt but can't, try `ls -l ~/.gvfs`. You should see something there that corresponds to your NTFS partition.

Comment: Yeah, this turned out to be my favorite way to get a persistant mount.   I tried pysdm above and it didn't help me at all.

Comment: My NTFS drives work, but I don't see anything in ~/.gvfs