# Unable to mount USBDRIVE Error creating moint point: Permission denied

Tags: usb, mount

Whenever I plug a usb into my computer a window pops up and says

> Unable to mount [Name of USB]
>   Error creating moint point: Permission denied

```
steve@goliath:/$ uname -a
Linux goliath 3.2.0-32-generic #51-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 26 21:33:09 UTC 2012 x86_64 
x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

steve@goliath:/$ sudo fdisk -l

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't   
support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sda: 120.0 GB, 120034123776 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 14593 cylinders, total 234441648 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0f716ee1

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1   234441647   117220823+  ee  GPT

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdb'! The util fdisk 
doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdb: 1500.3 GB, 1500301910016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 182401 cylinders, total 2930277168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0f710ee1

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1  2930277167  1465138583+  ee  GPT

Disk /dev/sdc: 16.0 GB, 16005464064 bytes
74 heads, 10 sectors/track, 42244 cylinders, total 31260672 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xc3072e18

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1            8064    31260671    15626304    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)

steve@goliath:/$ sudo mkdir /media/external
mkdir: cannot create directory `/media/external': Permission denied

steve@goliath:/$ sudo mkdir /media/usb0
mkdir: cannot create directory `/media/usb0': Permission denied

steve@goliath:/$ sudo ls -l / | grep media
drwxr-xr-x   3 root  root  4096 Oct  3 22:48 media

steve@goliath:/$ ls /media/ -a
.  ..  MediaShare
```

MediaShare is the the directory on my server that has all my movies and music. If there is any information I left out please let me know.

How can something not be accessed by sudo/root? I have tried sudo su and the above.

Comment: Any help or ideas would be super, I am at a loss as to what to do.

Comment: You didn't say which version of Ubuntu this is on, but you might try to do this:  `sudo chown myusername /media`  -  And if it is a modern version, you will be much happier if you install pmount as described here:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/88523/creating-a-mount-point-if-it-does-not-exist/941726#941726

Answer (score 0):

If your USB stick is formatted ntfs make sure you have the NTFS Fuse programs installed.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g ntfsprogs;
```

ntfs support seems to have been removed from the default install since 12.04LTS.

(reboot after you install ntfsprogs and ntfs-3g as they get built into the kernel)

===

Also I see that your drives are formatted GPT. Fdisk is no longer the valid command to find information on your drives.

Use the parted command instead of fdisk.

```
sudo parted -l
```