# USB Drive won't mount

Tags: usb, mount, live-usb, toshiba-satellite

I have a Lexar 16GB USB stick and for some reason it won't mount. Ubuntu won't even recognize it.

Info about it...nothing much. I used it once as a Backtrack LiveUSB and *tried* to use it once as an Ubuntu Studio 12.10 LiveUSB (ended up with a Kernel Panic). So now I am trying to just reformat it (easiest/fastest way to wipe everything off) and just use it as a regular USB drive or maybe use it as a Backtrack LiveUSB again.

Is there any way I can force Ubuntu to recognize it? I know the port works as my USB mouse receiver works fine.

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (old hardware, I'll upgrade soonish) on a Toshiba Satellite A105.

**Edit:**

By using [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB) guide I was able to force-mount it, but it still doesn't show up in Places (PCManFM because I use LXDE) like it usually does. Another strange thing, neither does the Windows NTFS partition I set to automount.

It appears that my system has stopped auto-mounting things. The devices show up in their respective /media/deviceHere/ folders, but not under Places in PCManFM

---

Wierdness.

Oh well. However it was, I just had to delete/unmount anything with the name Lexar or External USB in the media folder and it is now recognized! Thanks anyways @manuel.

**Edit:**

Never mind, now it has disappeared again. If I want to access the /media/Lexar folder I have to be root and the Windows partition still doesn't show up.

HELP!

Comment: When would I run this?

Comment: Please remove the stick, look whether the /media/[username] directory is empty and report other things here.

Comment: Ok, will do. When do I run the `dmesg | tail` command?

Comment: Then plug in the stick, open a terminal and execute `dmesg | tail`. Please post the output.

Comment: ok...doing. After removing the stick it displays the Windows partition as a folder, but not in PCManFM Places. Nautilus sees it a displays it fine. Will now plug in and run the command

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8994/discussion-between-rpi-awesomeness-and-manuel)

Comment: Have you tried `pmount`? :  https://askubuntu.com/questions/88523/creating-a-mount-point-if-it-does-not-exist/941726#941726 - instructions for installing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, in a [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/8994) we haven't found a reason why PCManFM doesn't automount. So here we create an fstab entry for the stick:

1. We need to create the folder for the stick and get the device id.
    Open a terminal.
   The folder can be created via

   ```
   sudo mkdir /media/mystick
   ```

   In addition I would make the user the owner and give him the right to read/write:

   ```
   sudo chown [user]:[group] /media/mystick
   ```

   ```
   sudo chmod +rw /media/mystick
   ```
2. Now the fstab entry:

   - Install `libblkid1` to see device specific information: `sudo apt-get install libblkid1`
   - Enter `sudo blkid` and look for the stick. The output could be:

     ```
     /dev/sda2: UUID="32a4b76f-246e-486e-8495-31b8a781fb4c" TYPE="swap" 
     /dev/sde1: LABEL="MAXELL" UUID="8D67-D560" TYPE="vfat"
     ```
   - Then we create the fstab entry: `sudo gedit /etc/fstab` and append the line

     ```
     UUID=8D67-D560     /media/mystick   auto    rw,user,auto    0    0
     ```

     (and afterwards give a empty new line to avoid warnings):
     [image: fstab entry]

To mount the stick, open a terminal and type

```
mount /media/mystick
```

Because of the entry `auto` it should be mounted automatically if you remove and plug in the stick again.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Manuel! I logged out and back in again and it works fine now??? Oh well. Thanks again!

Comment: I hope so. If not, tell me.

Comment: Personally, I recommend you use UUIDs in the future. easier/faster/more reliable

Comment: This is totally cool that you posted the results determined in chat, Manuel.  Thank you for doing this.

Comment: What happens if the USB is not present on System Boot? Wont boot take a long time?