# My computer won't boot after trying to mount a Flash drive

Tags: boot, mount, flash, usb-drive

I'm a beginner, I'v just installed ubuntu on my computer
The problem is that I plugged my flash drive but nothing happened and it didn't appear in the launcher, I read online and then found that I have to mount it manually, so I tried the method in here: 
[USB Drive won't mount](https://askubuntu.com/questions/301506/usb-drive-wont-mount)
but it did't work + appears like I've corrupted something :( ..

All i did after that was restarting my computer but emergency mode keeps appearing every time I reboot it.

I tried to reinstall my OS but my bootable usb that I have used before won't appear in the boot list.

What should I do? :(

---UPDATE---

I tried "shutdown -rF now" and reinstalled my OS
But all the files are gone now because the option that would't delete them was greyed out.

Anyway, If there is any solution that could help in case this happened again please provide it :) Thank you.