# Creating Your Own Mount Point for USB Drive

Tags: usb, mount, fstab, automount

I have an external USB drive which is always plugged in. I have modified fstab and created a folder in media so that the drive is mounted at media/drive_name. However, is automount is enabled, every time I restart the system the drive get remounted in media/user_name/drive name. I would like to keep automount on for other devices, but for this specific one have my own mount point. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Would you settle for running a script?

Comment: What modifications did you make to `fstab`?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/214646/how-to-configure-the-default-automount-location. Read that. It might explain some stuff.

Comment: I would settle for a script.

Comment: I added the following to my fstab: /dev/sdb1 /media/drive_name defaults 0 2.. However, when I restart the system it will appear as /dev/sdc1 and be mounted as /media/user_name/drive_name. If I then unmount it, edit fstab to use sdc1, and remount it, on reboot it appears as sdb1 again.. I have to go through this process each time I reboot.

Comment: @Zacharee1: Thank you for the link, but I would like this to apply only to this drive. Other plugged in drives can be automounted to the user's home folder.

Comment: @SteveKiss I was referring more to the accepted answer. Would you mind  mounting it manually, though?

Comment: @Zacharee1, I see. I guess I will have to mount it manually with a script each time? Is that the right direction? I don't mind this as long as I don't have to deal with it on each reboot.

Comment: @SteveKiss Yes. You should make a script to mount it, then move the `sh` file to the startup directory, which I will search for and include in the answer I will write if this is what you want.

Comment: @Zacharee1, that would be great. Thank you!

Comment: @SteveKiss Still finding good ways to add a startup script. Should be a few minutes.

Comment: @SteveKiss OK. Try it.

Comment: @SteveKiss You should use UUIDs instead of `/dev/sdXY`. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears

Comment: @Zacharee1, worked like a charm. Thank you!!

Comment: Good! @SteveKiss

Comment: I use fstab by UUID for /mnt SATA drives.  pmount is for named USB drives.  It always automatically  ensures they have the correct name under /media.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/88523/creating-a-mount-point-if-it-does-not-exist/941726#941726

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

1. Make your script: make a new text document and put this in:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh  
   mkdir -p /path/to/custom-mount  
   sudo umount /dev/sdaX ((This is the drive you want to mount in the custom location))  
   sudo mount -t filesystem-type -o rw /dev/sdaX /path/to/custom-mount
   ```
2. Put this script under `/etc/init.d`.
3. Make it executable by running `sudo chmod -x /etc/init.d/script-name`.
4. Run `update-rc.d script-name defaults`.

Hopefully, this will unmount your drive and then remount it under the folder you want.

Comment: @ThomasW. I think he already has that. Will it be removed upon reboot, when the drive gets unmounted?

Comment: missed that.  sorry.  It should stay but it's still a good form to make a note that you should make sure the mount point exists yet.  In fact if you change `/bin/sh` to `/bin/bash` we can add in some error check code but meh

Comment: @ThomasW. I think it would be better to keep it simple.

Comment: Yes, like - automatic.  pmount takes care of this problem all by itself.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/88523/creating-a-mount-point-if-it-does-not-exist/941726#941726